# Does Clojure have an equivalent to Python's if __name__=="__main__"?

Tags: clojure, program-entry-point, getmodulefilename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the clojure equivalent of the Python idiom “if **name** == '**main**'”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973106/what-is-the-clojure-equivalent-of-the-python-idiom-if-name-main)

I would use `-main`, but it only runs in compiled mode, not interpreted mode.

I would use `(if (.isAbsolute (java.io.File. *file*)) (main *command-line-args*))`, but that runs during any `(load)`ing of scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of [What is the clojure equivalent of the Python idiom "if __name__ == '__main__'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973106/what-is-the-clojure-equivalent-of-the-python-idiom-if-name-main). I guess I'm supposed to "vote to close this question as a duplicate" but I can't figure out how; someone feel free to edit this or inform me of the proper technique.

Comment: Yeah, you need 3000 rep to vote to close.